# Location GPS iPhone SDK

Tags: ios4, gps, coordinates

I would like to grab my iPhone's current GPS Location and then show the dictionary of the longitude and latitude location in my text field. Only issue is I do not know how to grab the longtiude and latitude of the device and only a local one I declare.

Could someone help me figure out how to grab the location of the iPhone and covert it into the coord.longitude and coord.latitude method?

Code below:

http://pastie.org/1328246

Answer (score 0):

have you reviewed any example in the iOS Reference Library? Here is an example of getting the user location (`CLLocationCoordinate2D`) http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html

[edit] here is another example, from iCodeBlog : http://icodeblog.com/2010/09/03/adding-local-weather-conditions-to-your-app-part-12-implementing-corelocation/

Comment: I can grab the coordinates, just not an address location :P